# How to fix the battery drain during Suspend on Lenovo Ideapad3 running Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: suspend, power-management, lenovo, hibernate, ideapad

Ubuntu 21.10 on Lenovo IdeaPad3 is mostly a fantastic experience. The only problem is that the battery drains 30% or more overnight when the laptop is in Suspend mode.

I have seen discussions that recommend change the Sleep mode to Hibernate, but also many warnings against doing this.

a) Has anyone tried to enable Sleep to Hibernate on Lenovo IdeaPad3? If so, what method?
b) If Sleep to Hibernate is a bad idea, then what is the alternative?

Comment: What happens or doesn't during suspension has nothing to do with the OS. Please check UEFI settings for something that keeps ports enabled/"alive" namely Wakeup On LAN features and similar. Also, of course, update UEFI.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't go to suspend.

Comment: Installing TLP helps marginally. The fundamental issue is of the computer not going to Hibernate mode.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to install TLP? It helps a lot if Battery management is the case. Try to install it ( see link below).

Here is the Documentation for Ubuntu:

https://linrunner.de/tlp/installation/ubuntu.html

Comment: TLP won't change what is basically controlled by the motherboard's firmware.